# Why does my code filter out the characters I'm not asking it to filter? (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I've only asked my code to filter out '-' and '+', but it also filters out '//' which it should not.

Anyone have any idea why it does this?

```
with open("some_file_1.txt") as f, open("some_file_2.txt") as g:
    flines = f.readlines()
    glines = g.readlines()

    d = difflib.Differ()
    diff = d.compare(flines, glines)

with open('merged_tp.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in diff:
        print line
        new_line = re.sub('[+-?]', '', line)
        file_out.write(new_line)
```

Comment: Why do you have that question mark in your regular expression?

Comment: 1- the 2 lines where you build the difference should be dedented as you're already done with reading the input files. 2- For such a simple substitution a regex may be overkill, just `file_out.write(line.replace('+','').replace('-',''))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character set `[+-?]` means "any character between `+` and `?`".

`+` has the integer ordinal 43. `?` has the integer ordinal 63. The range 43–63 includes the following characters: `+,-./0123456789:;<=>?`

The character set `[+-]` means "either `+` or `-`", which I think is what you want.